# Is this the correct way to implement 'setOnClickListener()'?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
##For accepting a string from a EditText on clicking a button##

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //save button
    //be notified when the button is clicked
    saves=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    saves.setOnClickListener(onSave);
}
private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Restaurant r = new Restaurant();
        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_enter);
        EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address_enter);
        r.setName(name.getText().toString());
        r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());               
     }
};
}
```

Problem is that my application crashes everytime I start it. The logcat says that the error is in the line saves.setOnClickListener(onSave);

Comment: Maybe because saves is null, post logcat. --- Check if the layout (activity_main) contains save button.

Comment: my layout was pointing at a different xml file, thank you for your help

Comment: The problem is fixed? I will post the comment as answer so you can accept it and we avoid to keep this question w/o an answer.

Comment: actually i created a different activity and forgot to add it's name.
Yeah the problem is solved :)

Comment: So the problem was caused by the lack of the activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: yeah, it created a different activity apart from main activity, and i was working on that one. I didn't realize that, indeed my own fault.

Comment: Since the problem is not what i said, post an answer and accept your answer (with what caused the problem and how you fixed it).

Comment: changed this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
to
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```