# Cannot invoke getText()on the array type String[]

Tags: android

Hi got some problems that I cant fix in any way, google and searched cant find anything so please help.

Stuff that I use (not in order)

```
String[] SDCard = {"/sdcard/WhatToEat/Dishes.txt/"};
EditText mTextInput;
ListView mtextOutput;






    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.save) {
        File WriteSD =new File("/sdcard/WhatToEat/");
        String[] SDCard = {"/sdcard/WhatToEat/Dishes.txt/"};

        if(WriteSD.exists()){
            try {
                WriteSD.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileWriter fileWritter = null;
        try {
            fileWritter = new FileWriter(WriteSD.getName(),true);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        try {
            bufferWritter.write("/sdcard/WhatToEat/WriteSD/Dishes.txt/");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        bufferWritter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        bufferWritter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        String text = mTextInput.getText().toString();
        WriteSD.setText(text+"/n"+SDCard.getText().toString());
```

The Error on getText() - Cannot invoke getText() on the array type String[]
Any fix or go around? Thanks in advance :)

LogCat

```
05-16 16:48:12.180: D/dalvikvm(803): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 5% free 2908K/3048K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
05-16 16:48:12.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(803): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.377MB for 500416-byte allocation
05-16 16:48:12.220: D/dalvikvm(803): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3394K/3540K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
05-16 16:48:12.270: D/AndroidRuntime(803): Shutting down VM
05-16 16:48:12.270: W/dalvikvm(803): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a86ba8)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803): Process: com.example.whattoeat, PID: 803
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whattoeat/com.example.whattoeat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.example.whattoeat.MainActivity.setupWidgets(MainActivity.java:102)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.example.whattoeat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-16 16:48:12.280: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  ... 11 more
```

setupWidgets

```
private void setupWidgets() {
        Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextInput=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mtextOutput=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP lacks minimal understanding of Java API's.

Comment: Hi, try to paste all the relevant code, in order. also paste the exception that you are getting

Comment: Updated and pasted more of the code

Comment: The error is happening on the setUpWidgets method. Can you post the code of that method as well?

Comment: Done, posted under logcat

Comment: Hmmm check that all the names of your widgets are the same in your xml file. The error you re getting is because it can't find one of those controls

Comment: It was `save.setOnClickListener(this);` Any fix? I kind of need it

Comment: Yeah 2 possible things can be happening
1. Your button doesn't have the correct id (R.is.save) Check your xml to see if it's the same
2. You are not calling `setContentView(R.layout.the_name_of_your_layout)` You need to call it before setupwidgets

Comment: Have done both, still not working :/ The button's id is "save" and I have the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` before the setupWidgets

Comment: This is my problem found it in another question, I don't understand how they solved it tho. Help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044173/is-this-the-correct-way-to-implement-setonclicklistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use an array? Can't you use a regular string instead?

anyway, this should work

```
WriteSD.setText(text+"/n"+SDCard[0]);
```

Comment: Fixed that error but got another one on .setText - The method setText(String) is undefined for the type File

Comment: I just read that bit of your code. WriteSD is not a TextView, so you can't set the text with setText().

`WriteSD = new File(text+"/n"+SDCard[0]);`

And you should listen to the comment of @Lisa, change your declaration of SDCard. Will be easier to work with

Comment: Done and Done. Another error on SDCard[0]); ..... - The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Comment: Well now that you changed the declaration of SDCard you no longer need to use the index [0]. Just use `SDCard` instead of `SDCard[0]`

Comment: Got rid of all errors thanks, but the application dosent start. Just tells me "application stopped." Any thoughts?

Comment: Post your logcat output please, otherwise I can't tell what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring SDCard as an array of String objects which contains one String, rather than as a single String.

You can fix this by changing your declaration of SDCard to

```
String SDCard = "/sdcard/WhatToEat/Dishes.txt/";
```

Comment: Also worked, still got error on getText() tho. - The method getText() is undefined for the type String